# Would using Fury / Arms armor while running in Protection spec improve my warrior's solo dps?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I'd like to create a secondary set of armor to use while soloing that improves my DPS without requiring me to switch specs. Some of the protection spells require dodge or parry to proc, and I know dodge / parry also increases my critical strike chance due to Riposte, but I'm still curious if I could improve my DPS by replacing dodge or parry with Critical Strike or Haste anyway?

Comment: Any increase to your crit/mastery should increase your dps provided you are not entirely eliminating the other stats, but why do you not want to switch specs?  with a macro you can equip an entire set of gear and change your spec, all with a single click

Comment: @WayneWeibel Don't even need a macro, WoW has built in gear-sets now. ^^

Comment: Yeah, but you can use a macro to automate switching both the gear set and the active spec with a single click - instead of going into the character UI and talent windows to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Your DPS would go up, offcourse, but your tankiness will go down.
So ask yourself, are you running instances (dungeons, raids,...) in the role of a tank, then why do you need more dps?
If you are doing quests solo, just change to fury or arms (I advise fury). It is that much quicker to level.

Answer (score 0):

A TL;DR answer is YES.

Actually a tank specification with dps gear set is still valuable when leveling - it makes you not so easy to die, gives you the ability to pull multiple mobs to make questing more effective.

However at max level, I strongly do not recommend you do so because it will make you weaker as a tank in dungeons or raids. As to solo some old raid... I have to say warrior is really not a good class for soloing because of lack of healing spells. If you like solo, hunter or death knight might be good choices.